# Associations with entities (proxy error)

Tags: proxy, doctrine-orm, associations, zend-framework2, entities

i've the follow entities:

- User
- Address
- Country

My user connects to Address and Address to Country. I've a magic __setter and __getter, and when I use `$addresses = $user->__get('addresses');`, it retrieves my address(es).

dump:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#463 (13) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(19) "User\Entity\Address"
    ["inputFilter"]=>
    NULL
    ["addressid"]=>
    int(21)
    ["street"]=>
    string(9) "Lange heg"
    ["number"]=>
    int(19)
    ["addition"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["zipcode"]=>
    string(6) "7039CA"
    ["user"]=>
    string(16) "User\Entity\User"
    ["country"]=>
    string(50) "DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\User\Entity\Country"
    ["creator_id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["creation_date"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["last_modifier_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["last_modified_date"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Only my country don't get the right object (from the country entity). My associations:

User-entity:

```
/**
 * Id from user
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Address", mappedBy="user")
 * @var Address
 * @access protected
 */
protected $addresses;
```

Address-entity:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", inversedBy="addresses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
 * @var User[]
 * @access protected
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\Country", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @var Country[]
 * @access protected
 */
protected $country;
```

Country-entity:

```
/**
 * Id from a country
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Address", mappedBy="country")
 * @var int
 * @access protected
 */
protected $id;
```

In my address entity it stores the user_id and country_id in the database. How can i get my countries from my users? Without returning the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure on this, but the if you get the country, the proxy would normally return a country entity. Have you tried to actually fetching the country and see what kind of object you get?

```
$addresses[0]->__get('country');
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty stupid. I didn't know that it returned a proxy because of "lazy loading". So he knew the countries all the time. If i (as you said) get my countryname or something, it just returned the country. This proxy came, because i didn't get anything from the country entity. Stupid.